# How to loop through lines in a file which contains * in each line

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

I have a file that contains about 800 lines. All the lines contains 1 * character in it.

I need to loop through the lines in the file so I used the following simple for loop

```
for i in $(cat file_path); do echo $i; done
```

Unfortunately it did not work.

When I try it with another files but the lines in the file do not contains the * character, the loop is working fine.

How can I solve this?

Comment: See the first [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to use the following format :

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
while IFS= read -r line <&3
do
    echo "$line"
done 3< myfile.txt
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Test is :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen/test/shell# ./linebylibe.sh 
ff
dd
gg
tt
tt
ww
ee
```

And my myfile.txt is :

```
root@debian:/home/mohsen/test/shell# cat myfile.txt 
ff
dd
gg
tt
tt
ww
ee
```

Comment: This will fail if line contains backslash characters.

Comment: I updated. my answer.

Comment: That still fails for lines containing backslashes or beginning or ending in blanks or lines like "-n", "-nene". See @cuonglm's for the correct answer.

Comment: I solved with $IFS variable.

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem, please see all great explain from @StéphaneChazelas's answer which I referred in my answer.

Comment: has been updated.

Answer (score 5):

You have some troubles with your code:

- Leaving [variables and command substitution unquoted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/38906)
- Using echo with [arbitrary variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/38906)

You can fix them by using `while` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r line <&3; do
  { printf '%s\n' "$line"; } 3<&-
done 3< file

[ -z "$line" ] || printf %s "$line"
```

A note that [using while loops to process text files is considered bad practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/38906) in POSIX shell.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `while`:

```
while read line; do echo "$line"; done < test.txt
```

or define separate character `IFS`:

```
SAVEIFS=$IFS; IFS="\n"; for i in $(cat test.txt); do echo "$i"; done; IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

Comment: This will fail if line contains backslash characters, leaving command substitution unquote is very dangerous and actually doesn't show the OP's issue. You should also save `IFS` and restore it after the loop.

Comment: Your `for` loop still fail when line contains `*`, that's the same as OP's problem. And setting `IFS="\n"` is wrong, it set `IFS` to `\ ` and `n`, not a newline.