# Wildcards for filepaths aren't working in grep

Tags: shell, grep, quoting

I need to grep words like these:

```
ABC-DEF
AB2-DEF
AB3-DEF
AB-DEF
```

So I was trying:

```
grep AB*-DEF
grep -w -AB*-DEF
grep -w AB*DEF
```

But neither of them are working.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`*` in a regex is not like a filename glob.  It means 0 or more of the previous character/pattern.  So your examples would be looking for a `A` then 0 or more `B` then `-DEF`

`.` in regex means "any character" so you could fix your pattern by using

```
grep 'AB.*DEF'
```

Comment: This will match many other patterns e.g. `ABCGLHHJKH90-DEF`

Comment: True heemayl, but it is in keeping with the filesystem glob expansion like Jeevan seemed to be trying for in the question.

Answer (score 3):

As far as your patterns are concerned, this would be the safest to match only intended strings:

```
grep 'AB.\{0,1\}-DEF' file.txt
```

Or

```
grep -E 'AB.?-DEF' file.txt
```

`.` matches any single character, `?` and `\{0,1\}` matches the previous token zero or one time, so in total `.?` and `.\{0,1\}`will match zero or one character before `-DEF`.

If you use `AB.*-DEF` or `AB.*DEF`, `grep` will greedily match unintended strings, for example:

```
ABCG-DEF
ABCGLHHJKH90-DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
grep 'AB.*-DEF' file.txt
```

Comment: That command crashed my machine. I had a `AB.\(a*\)\{10000\}-DEF` file in the current directory.

Comment: I edited my post, quoted the search pattern. Thank you.

Comment: @nghnam: Please take time to edit your answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203116/38906), too. Or deleting it, otherwise other people will be confused with the information in that answer.

Answer (score 0):

The wildcards in your regular expressions are expanded by the shell.  The shell treats them as filename metacharacters.  So, you have to tell the shell to *not* evaluate them as filename metacharacters and you do that by quoting them using single quotes, double quotes, or backslash character just before the metacharacter.  Then, the shell sends the expression as such to the `grep` utility which handles the regular expression.